# What do the red characters in the source code of the web page mean in edge?

Tags: html

[image]

This is the content of a file returned by my server, but when I open the source code of the page,it like that[image]

The red characters are not showing, I want to know what the red characters mean

Comment: that's syntax highlighting probably and you are trying to see as page source something that's not strictly page source so you have syntax errors of course

Comment: What are you opening it with